# Html.BeginForm with overload causes form action to be '/cgi-bin?action=Index&controller=Home' and so the HomeController is bypassed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

Because I wanted to assign an id to a form element my code was `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "indexform"}))`

This resulted in markup `<form action="/cgi-bin?action=Index&amp;controller=Home" id="indexform" method="post" style="position: relative;">`

My HomeController `ActionResult Index` was completely bypassed.

Notice the '/cgi-bin'. This might be the problem and I think the culprit may be parameter 'FormMethod.Post' but I could not enter null there.

(BTW I worked around the id requirement by using jQuery `var form = $("#btnShowProperty").closest("form");`)

I did quite a bit of Googling on this with no luck.

Comment: Is the method that generated that view in `HomeController`? If you specify them explicitly -  `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "indexform"}))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing `null` for the action and controller in the first two arguments. Instead, pass the name of your action and controller and it will work.

Example, if your action is "Index" and your controller is "Home", then use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "indexform"})) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No I tried that and the markup was 100% exactly the same.

BTW how do you get the pretty colors in the code of your post?

Comment: Then you have another problem, perhaps in your MVC configurations. Post the route configuration so we can validate it for you.

Comment: The route config is longish and indeed there may be a problem but it has been working for a long time with all sorts of strange URLs hitting the app. But I essentially want to know why cgi-bin is added to action as it is totally unexpected AFAIK and if that is indeed standard practice then I can work around that.

Comment: What are you asking if it is *standard practice*? Are you asking if the code in my answer a standard practice? Yes, it's actually the syntax that you should use. As for where the `cgi-bin` is coming from and how your code has been working all the time, I cannot answer those without looking at your code. AFAIK, it's not something that comes from MVC in normal use. Perhaps it's coming from your hosting environment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mixing web pages and mvc especially using MapPageRoute AND MapRoute in Route.config. See full answer [@Url.Action(“Action”, “Controller”) returns “/cgi-bin?action=Action&controller=Controller”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964532/url-actionaction-controller-returns-cgi-binaction-actionampcontroll/38984757#38984757)